# Does adding to degree n polynomial terms with negative exponents still have n roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

A polynomial has n roots. You can add terms less than n and still have a polynomial with n roots. Does this continue if you take negative exponents?

Eg.
$$ax^2 + bx^1 + cx^0 + dx^{-1}...$$

Edit: I guess this isn't a polynomial per se, but does it still have n roots?

Comment: If the highest positive power is $\,n \gt 0\,$ and the lowest negative power is $\,-m \le 0\,$ then you can write it as $\,\frac{1}{x^m} \, P_{n+m}\,$ where $\,P_{n+m}\,$ is a polynomial of degree $\,n+m\,$, which thus has $\,n+m\,$ roots.

Comment: FYI, this kind of expression is called a [Laurent polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaurentPolynomial.html), which is a special case of a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function).

Comment: $x-1/x$ has two roots.

Comment: Note that an $n$-degree polynomial has _at most_ $n$ roots. It only is guaranteed to have exactly $n$ roots if you work over an algebraically closed field (e.g., $\mathbb C$) and you count double/triple/... roots multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not true. For ex, $P(x)=x$ has only one root but
$$
Q(x)=P(x)-3+\frac 1{x}
$$
has two roots ($Q=0$ is a quadratic equation).

Answer (score 8):

The [Laurent polynomal](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaurentPolynomial.html) $P(x) = ax^n + bx^{n-1} + cx^{n-2} + ... + ux^{-m+2} + vx^{-m+1} + wx^{-m}$ can be equivalently expressed as the quotient $\frac{ax^{m+n} + bx^{m+n-1} + cx^{m+n-2} + ... + ux^2 + vx + w}{x^m}$, whose roots are the roots of its numerator, a polynomial of degree $n + m$.  The maximum number of roots is thus $n + m$, the sum of the most positive and most negative exponents.